# Python mechanize doesn't work when HTTPS and Proxy Authentication required

Tags: python, https, proxy, mechanize

I use Python 2.7.2 and Mechanize 0.2.5.
When I access the Internet, I have to go through a proxy server. I wrote the following codes, but an URLError occurred at the last line.. Does anyone have any solution about this?

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.set_proxies({
    "http"  : "192.168.20.130:8080",
    "https" : "192.168.20.130:8080",})
br.add_proxy_password("username", "password")

br.open("http://www.google.co.jp/")  # OK
br.open("https://www.google.co.jp/") # Proxy Authentication Required
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use Mechanize, it's outdated. Take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) it will 
make your life a lot easier. Using proxies with requests it's just this:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  "http": "10.10.1.10:3128",
  "https": "10.10.1.10:1080",
}

requests.get("http://example.org", proxies=proxies)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know requests module. I'm trying it now. How can I specify username and password for Proxy Authentication?

Comment: you need to use the proxy url like: username:mypassword@10.10.1.10:3128

Comment: Thank you. Surely your way is accepted by basic authentication. When proxy server requires digest auth, username and password cannot be embedded in proxy-url. I tried requests.auth.HTTPProxyAuth, but proxy returned 407.