# How to pass proxy-authentication (requires digest auth) by using python requests module

Tags: python, digest-authentication, python-requests, proxy-server

I was using Mechanize module a while ago, and now try to use Requests module. 
([Python mechanize doesn't work when HTTPS and Proxy Authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505349/))

I have to go through proxy-server when I access the Internet. 
The proxy-server requires authentication. I wrote the following codes.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

proxies = {"http":"192.168.20.130:8080"}
auth = HTTPProxyAuth("username", "password")

r = requests.get("http://www.google.co.jp/", proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
```

The above codes work well when proxy-server requires basic authentication. 
Now I want to know what I have to do when proxy-server requires digest authentication. 
HTTPProxyAuth seems not to be effective in digest authentication (r.status_code returns 407).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wrote the class that can be used in proxy authentication (based on digest auth). 
I borrowed almost all codes from requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth.

```
import requests
import requests.auth

class HTTPProxyDigestAuth(requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth):
    def handle_407(self, r):
        """Takes the given response and tries digest-auth, if needed."""

        num_407_calls = r.request.hooks['response'].count(self.handle_407)

        s_auth = r.headers.get('Proxy-authenticate', '')

        if 'digest' in s_auth.lower() and num_407_calls < 2:

            self.chal = requests.auth.parse_dict_header(s_auth.replace('Digest ', ''))

            # Consume content and release the original connection
            # to allow our new request to reuse the same one.
            r.content
            r.raw.release_conn()

            r.request.headers['Authorization'] = self.build_digest_header(r.request.method, r.request.url)
            r.request.send(anyway=True)
            _r = r.request.response
            _r.history.append(r)

            return _r

        return r

    def __call__(self, r):
        if self.last_nonce:
            r.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = self.build_digest_header(r.method, r.url)
        r.register_hook('response', self.handle_407)
        return r
```

Usage:

```
proxies = {
    "http" :"192.168.20.130:8080",
    "https":"192.168.20.130:8080",
}
auth = HTTPProxyDigestAuth("username", "password")

# HTTP
r = requests.get("http://www.google.co.jp/", proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
r.status_code # 200 OK

# HTTPS
r = requests.get("https://www.google.co.jp/", proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
r.status_code # 200 OK
```

Comment: I get the error: 'HTTPProxyDigestAuth' object has no attribute 'last_nonce'.  When I try and use your class.  I'll look into it.

Comment: No need to implement your own now, `requests` now has built in support for proxies, e.g. `proxies = { 'https' : 'https://user:password@ip:port' } ; 
r = requests.get('https://url', proxies=proxies)` see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

Comment: @BurnsBA @MattClimbs @yutaka I can confirm that the use of requests in Python 3 with https and the `user:password@ip:port` works great.

Comment: This snippet does not work anymore with recent versions of requests, because it now puts request parameters in a thread local storage. Also, even after having fixed the code, [this will not work for connecting to HTTPS website through proxy](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2526#issuecomment-89514502).

Comment: So @Tey' is there a way to fix this? (Use the digest in the proxy)

Comment: @dcalap Check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60031108/5099839) I've just posted

Comment: `proxies = {'https': 'http://user:password@ip:port'}` worked for me. Note `http://`.

Comment: @omegastripes if it worked for you, it means that it uses Basic Auth, not digest, which is what OP asked

Comment: @BurnsBA the [requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies) makes clear that the built-in proxy support works only for Basic Auth, not for Digest, which is what OP asked

Answer (score 38):

**No need to implement your own!** *in most cases*

Requests has built in support for proxies, for basic authentication:

```
proxies = { 'https' : 'https://user:password@proxyip:port' } 
r = requests.get('https://url', proxies=proxies)
```

see more on the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies)

Or in case you need digest authentication `HTTPDigestAuth` may help.
*Or you might need try to extend it like yutaka2487 did bellow.*

Note: must use ip of proxy server not its name!

Comment: It only works for Basic authentication, not Digest authentication which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: It will not work because `HTTPDigestAuth` only supports authentication with the final website server (`WWW-Authenticate`/`Authorization` headers, 401 status), not the proxy server (`Proxy-Authenticate`/`Proxy-Authorization` headers, 407 status). You need a solution similar to the one given by @yutaka2487 for that, but it only works for contacting a HTTP server through proxy, not a HTTPS server, because requests/urllib3 backend does not report proxy error when tunneling HTTPS connections, so Digest auth cannot work properly.

Comment: @Tey' just consider `or you might need try to extend it like yutaka2487 did bellow`

Answer (score 9):

I've written a Python module (available [here](https://gist.github.com/Tey/ded2486da8a69bb84d2dce94e2e09ff7#file-requests_digest_proxy-py)) which makes it possible to authenticate with a HTTP proxy using the digest scheme. It works when connecting to HTTPS websites (through monkey patching) and allows to authenticate with the website as well. This should work with latest `requests` library for both Python 2 and 3.

The following example fetches the webpage https://httpbin.org/ip through HTTP proxy `1.2.3.4:8080` which requires HTTP digest authentication using user name `user1` and password `password1`:

```
import requests
from requests_digest_proxy import HTTPProxyDigestAuth

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = {
        'http': 'http://1.2.3.4:8080/',
        'https': 'http://1.2.3.4:8080/'
}
s.auth = HTTPProxyDigestAuth('user1', 'password1')

print(s.get('https://httpbin.org/ip').text)
```

Should the website requires some kind of HTTP authentication, this can be specified to `HTTPProxyDigestAuth` constructor this way:

```
# HTTP Basic authentication for website
s.auth = HTTPProxyDigestAuth(('user1', 'password1'),
        auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('user1', 'password0'))
print(s.get('https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user1/password0').text))

# HTTP Digest authentication for website
s.auth = HTTPProxyDigestAuth(('user1', 'password1'),,
        auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth('user1', 'password0'))
print(s.get('https://httpbin.org/digest-auth/auth/user1/password0').text)
```

Comment: I tried using this module and it gave me a 407 error.Please let me know if this still works

Comment: @Yash.S.Narang Scripts are still working for me with latest Python and requests versions. You can still get a 407 if proxy credentials are wrong, so check that maybe.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your Python module!

Comment: This works great, and works great when connecting to HTTPS site, where `requests-toolbelt` fails. Thank you so much!

Comment: I still have issues when connecting to HTTPS sites using this.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet works for both types of requests (`http` and `https`). Tested on the current version of requests (2.23.0).

```
import re
import requests
from requests.utils import get_auth_from_url
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
from requests.utils import parse_dict_header
from urllib3.util import parse_url

def get_proxy_autorization_header(proxy, method):
    username, password = get_auth_from_url(proxy)
    auth = HTTPProxyDigestAuth(username, password)
    proxy_url = parse_url(proxy)
    proxy_response = requests.request(method, proxy_url, auth=auth)
    return proxy_response.request.headers['Proxy-Authorization']


class HTTPSAdapterWithProxyDigestAuth(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def proxy_headers(self, proxy):
        headers = {}
        proxy_auth_header = get_proxy_autorization_header(proxy, 'CONNECT')
        headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = proxy_auth_header
        return headers


class HTTPAdapterWithProxyDigestAuth(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def proxy_headers(self, proxy):
        return {}

    def add_headers(self, request, **kwargs):
        proxy = kwargs['proxies'].get('http', '')
        if proxy:
            proxy_auth_header = get_proxy_autorization_header(proxy, request.method)
            request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = proxy_auth_header



class HTTPProxyDigestAuth(requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth):

    def init_per_thread_state(self):
        # Ensure state is initialized just once per-thread
        if not hasattr(self._thread_local, 'init'):
            self._thread_local.init = True
            self._thread_local.last_nonce = ''
            self._thread_local.nonce_count = 0
            self._thread_local.chal = {}
            self._thread_local.pos = None
            self._thread_local.num_407_calls = None

    def handle_407(self, r, **kwargs):
        """
        Takes the given response and tries digest-auth, if needed.
        :rtype: requests.Response
        """

        # If response is not 407, do not auth
        if r.status_code != 407:
            self._thread_local.num_407_calls = 1
            return r

        s_auth = r.headers.get('proxy-authenticate', '')

        if 'digest' in s_auth.lower() and self._thread_local.num_407_calls < 2:
            self._thread_local.num_407_calls += 1
            pat = re.compile(r'digest ', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            self._thread_local.chal = requests.utils.parse_dict_header(
                    pat.sub('', s_auth, count=1))

            # Consume content and release the original connection
            # to allow our new request to reuse the same one.
            r.content
            r.close()
            prep = r.request.copy()
            requests.cookies.extract_cookies_to_jar(prep._cookies, r.request, r.raw)
            prep.prepare_cookies(prep._cookies)

            prep.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = self.build_digest_header(prep.method, prep.url)
            _r = r.connection.send(prep, **kwargs)
            _r.history.append(r)
            _r.request = prep

            return _r

        self._thread_local.num_407_calls = 1
        return r

    def __call__(self, r):
        # Initialize per-thread state, if needed
        self.init_per_thread_state()
        # If we have a saved nonce, skip the 407
        if self._thread_local.last_nonce:
            r.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = self.build_digest_header(r.method, r.url)

        r.register_hook('response', self.handle_407)
        self._thread_local.num_407_calls = 1

        return r


session = requests.Session()
session.proxies = {
    'http': 'http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport',
    'https':  'http://username:password@proxyhost:proxyport'
}
session.trust_env = False

session.mount('http://', HTTPAdapterWithProxyDigestAuth())
session.mount('https://', HTTPSAdapterWithProxyDigestAuth())

response_http = session.get("http://ww3.safestyle-windows.co.uk/the-secret-door/")
print(response_http.status_code)

response_https = session.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506455/how-to-pass-proxy-authentication-requires-digest-auth-by-using-python-requests")
print(response_https.status_code)
```

Generally, the problem of proxy autorization is also relevant for other types of authentication (ntlm, kerberos) when connecting using the protocol HTTPS. And despite the large number of issues (since 2013, and maybe there are earlier ones that I did not find):

in requests: [Digest Proxy Auth](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2526), [NTLM Proxy Auth](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1582), [Kerberos Proxy Auth](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/issues/83)

in urlib3: [NTLM Proxy Auth](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/242), [NTLM Proxy Auth](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1434)

and many many others,the problem is still not resolved.

The root of the problem in the function `_tunnel` of the module `httplib`(python2)/`http.client`(python3). In case of unsuccessful connection attempt, it raises an `OSError` without returning a response code (407 in our case) and additional data needed to build the autorization header. Lukasa gave a explanation [here](https://github.com/requests/toolbelt/issues/136#issuecomment-190610347).
As long as there is no solution from maintainers of urllib3 (or requests), we can only use various workarounds (for example, use the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59154283/13114398) of @Tey' or do something like [this](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1434#issuecomment-517674113)).In my version of workaround, we pre-prepare the necessary authorization data by sending a request to the proxy server and processing the received response.

Comment: If putting together an app that would need to work in both environments where Basic _or_ Digest proxy auth might be needed, is there a pre-emptive way to determine whether you need to create/use an auth based on Digest or Basic?

Comment: If this is authentication on the site, then there is a way. You send a request, receive a response with a 401 code and an indication of what type of authentication is used. Having received this information, you can form a header with authentication data as needed and send a new request with this header. But if we are talking about proxy authentication in requests, then this will not work. If we send a request with incorrect data, we will receive an OSError. And in the text of the error there is no bulet of information about the type of authentication.

Comment: Thanks! ...that was my feeling/fear.  Is it just me, or is handling proxys, especially when they use authentication (which is the most common scenario in a corporate proxy env) a real problem in requests?  As an alternative concept - at least for windows machines - is there any simpler approach that will just piggy-back onto whatever is configured in the OS and use that?

Comment: Yes, I think this is really a problem of `requests`. The roots of this problem are in the library `http` of `python`. As for simple ways to send a http-request through a proxy for windows - I managed to do it through `curl` for a proxy with authentication Kerberos, there it was enough only to indicate that this type of authentication is used on the proxy-server and after that `curl` itself found all the necessary credentials stored in the system.

Comment: Exactly.  I've also put together a script in Powershell that I'm now replacing by Python.  In powershell it was trivial - it also figured out what auth method was being used and just used that.  ...simple and easy.  That this is such a unsupported mess in requests isn't good.

Answer (score 2):

You can use digest authentication by using `requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth` instead of `requests.auth.HTTPProxyAuth`

Comment: I wanted to pass proxy auth (based on digest auth). That is different from usual digest auth. So I needed to extend HTTPDigestAuth (see below).

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that still end up here, there appears to be a project called requests-toolbelt that has this plus other common but not built in functionality of requests.

https://toolbelt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#httpproxydigestauth

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work when connecting to HTTPS websites, only HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Actually, don't know about security of user:password in this soulution:

```
import requests
import os

http_proxyf = 'http://user:password@proxyip:port'
os.environ["http_proxy"] = http_proxyf
os.environ["https_proxy"] = http_proxyf

sess = requests.Session()
# maybe need sess.trust_env = True
print(sess.get('https://some.org').text)
```

Comment: This works only for Basic Auth, not for Digest Auth, which is what the OP asked

Comment: As this uses basic auth, the user and password are sent in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
import os


# in my case I had to add my local domain
proxies = {
  'http': 'proxy.myagency.com:8080',
  'https': 'user@localdomain:password@proxy.myagency.com:8080',
}


r=requests.get('https://api.github.com/events', proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: This works only for Basic Auth, not for Digest, and thus do not answer the OP question

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that is not for http Basic Authentication - for example a transperant proxy within organization.

```
import requests

url      = 'https://someaddress-behindproxy.com'
params   = {'apikey': '123456789'}                     #if you need params
proxies  = {'https': 'https://proxyaddress.com:3128'}  #or some other port
response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, params=params)
```

I hope this helps someone.