# Why i am getting this error while deploying a flask app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, web-applications, pythonanywhere

i am trying to deploy a small web application for small scale usage and while deploying it, i recieved the following error in the error log. Can someone explain what happened here?

i am fairly new to web app deployment so if someone could provide some links to improve my knowledge, that'd be helpful too.

this the code i used:

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
import io
import csv
import os
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Program to find locations corresponding to 1791 lattitudes and longitudes.</h1>
                <h4>Please note that the file should be in csv format anf the data should be in the following format: <u>gps_latitude, gps_longitude</u></h4>

                <form action="/upload_confirm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" accept=".csv">
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """


@app.route('/upload_confirm', methods=["POST"])
def upload_confirmation():
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return """No file uploaded<br>
                    <form action="/">
                        <input type="submit" value="Retry">
                    </form>"""
    else:
        database=sqlite3.connect("C:\SQLiteStudio\data.db")
        cur=database.cursor()

        task1="""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS coordinates_table (
       sr_no int,
       gps_latitude DOUBLE PRECISION ,
       gps_longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
       license_key_allotted VARCHAR
   );"""

        task2="""INSERT INTO coordinates_table (sr_no,gps_latitude,gps_longitude,license_key_allotted) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"""

        cur.execute(task1)

        out=pd.read_csv(f)
        x=out
        if len(out)>1791:
            print("the file has too many coordinate values, would process first 1791 coordinates only")
            data_count=1791
        elif len(out)<199:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<398:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<597:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<796:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<995:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<1194:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<1393:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<1592:
            data_count=len(out)
        elif len(out)<1791:
            data_count=len(out)


        row=1
        x=[]
        while row<=199 and row <data_count :
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_1"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_2"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_3"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_4"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_5"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199
        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_6"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_7"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<a and row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_8"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1

        a=row+199

        while row<data_count:
            x=[row,out.iloc[row,0],out.iloc[row,1],"key_9"]
            cur.execute(task2,x)
            database.commit()
            row+=1


        if len(out)>1791:
            out.drop(out.head(1791).index, inplace=True)
            out.to_csv(f, index=False)



        with open('location_file.csv', mode='a', newline='') as location_file:
            location_writer = csv.writer(location_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

            cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM coordinates_table""")
            coordinates=cur.fetchall()


            for i in range(len(coordinates)):

                key_check=coordinates[i]

                if key_check[3]=="key_1":

                    a=key_check
                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/kgpxta9p6y6zjdxnxh6qcwnke19bx8bt/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]
                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_2":
                    a=key_check
                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/zo3mglknal8p14y8jnq7m7pyy2vpxaha/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]
                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_3":
                    a=key_check
                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/aqfz9dx2xbv358yt3v8aia9cfhw97mxg/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]
                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_4":

                    a=key_check


                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/l9gtdjyqz4hy2plrxxmkrkvz46ztarg7/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]

                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_5":

                    a=key_check


                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/hxjlievzoxm8pdqr2vt27fb28tm553ox/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]

                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_6":

                    a=key_check


                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/lixj3orrkt79psvne2wbm5bymq4j8nu5/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]

                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_7":

                    a=key_check


                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/wjby24gltm99nrm3eq8ohgzxzjeafwmo/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]

                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])


                if key_check[3]=="key_8":

                    a=key_check


                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/zpuh5cx385m29b1mlgrxwrg3w7n6d1vo/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]

                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])

                if key_check[3]=="key_9":

                    a=key_check


                    url = "https://apis.mapmyindia.com/advancedmaps/v1/i1wsduwd81xnoi6o4awmjdvnn9cq8pop/rev_geocode"
                    querystring = {"lat":a[1],"lng":a[2]}
                    headers = {
                     'cache-control': "no-cache",
                     'postman-token': "e511fc69-0887-9eb7-8865-08b3afd25902"
                         }
                    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
                    res=response.text
                    res=ast.literal_eval(res)
                    res=res["results"]
                    res=res[0]
                    res=res["formatted_address"]

                    location_writer.writerow([a[1],a[2],res])

        cur.execute("""DROP TABLE coordinates_table;""")
        database.close()
        response = "attachment; filename=location_file.csv"
        return response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
2019-05-31 11:52:13,767: Exception on /upload_confirm [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 807, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 324, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 919, in _tunnel
    message.strip()))
OSError: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden
**NO MATCH**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apis.mapmyindia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /advancedmaps/v1/kgpxta9p6y6zjdxnxh6qcwnke19bx8bt/rev_geocode?lat=23.1267128&lng=70.02695465 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
**NO MATCH**
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
**NO MATCH**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2311, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1834, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1737, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 36, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1832, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1818, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/test_directory/task1webapp.py", line 176, in upload_confirmation
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jaypaliwal/.virtualenvs/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apis.mapmyindia.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /advancedmaps/v1/kgpxta9p6y6zjdxnxh6qcwnke19bx8bt/rev_geocode?lat=23.1267128&lng=70.02695465 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',)))
```

Comment: It's something to do with your internet connection. If you trying to run your app from behind a proxy, like from your work internet for example, you will need to provide the proper credentials before it lets you reach that mapmyindia URL.

Try looking at this question on how to use the requests library when behind a proxy. It may help you. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506455/how-to-pass-proxy-authentication-requires-digest-auth-by-using-python-requests

Comment: set proxy first

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here: it looks like you might be using a free account on our site.  Free PythonAnywhere accounts can only make outbound HTTP/HTTPS connections to sites on a [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).  However, we're always happy to add sites to that list if they have an official public API, and I see that the site you're trying to connect to has a hostname with "API" in it, so it could well be something we can add.   Just send us an email at support@pythonanywhere.com with a link to the website's API documentation and we'll see if we can add it.