# How to use proxy in requests

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, proxy-server

I have got proxies from [leafproxies](https://www.leafproxies.com/), and they are giving me something like this. I don't really understand what this is. At the very end, I want to use it in `requests`.

Here's what they provide.

```
ipaddress:port:xxx:xxx
```

> I believe that `xxx:xxx` part is username and password but I am not really sure.

Can anyone guide me, how can I use it with python `requests`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
import requests
import os

#Syntax is http://username:password@ipaddress:port
http_proxyf = 'http://xxx:xxx@gPtYMLoPX84.5.maxrainbow.net:8877'
# Copy xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-au-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxx 
# and paste at first 
 
os.environ["http_proxy"] = http_proxyf
os.environ["https_proxy"] = http_proxyf

page=requests.get("https://google.com")
```

To check you can do this:

```
print(requests.get('https://api64.ipify.org?format=json').json())
```

This will return the ip address.

Comment: Thank you. You are really an unsung hero as your badge says. Also, can you please specify issues with my question or suggest edits? It had some issues I guess and has been closed and downvoted.

Comment: I can edit you question, should I?

Comment: Yes, please. I want to know the correction.

Comment: @MuhammadZubair check my edit. If you found anything wrong you can edit that my yourself.

Comment: That's quite fine. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506455/how-to-pass-proxy-authentication-requires-digest-auth-by-using-python-requests/45763866