# set HTTPS proxy with mechanize (python) - possible?

Tags: python, http, proxy, mechanize

I read the docs, googled, and the only thing i could find was:

[Python mechanize doesn't work when HTTPS and Proxy Authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505349/python-mechanize-doesnt-work-when-https-and-proxy-authentication-required)

which seems to indicate it is not possible.  I would rather not go dig through another library, does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: What about [this](https://gist.github.com/emergent/3983870).? It's ruby, but maybe, you can adapt solution.

Comment: I think that is general http proxy?  I am trying for https

Answer (score 1):

you can set HTTPS proxy in mechanize like this.

```
import mechanize
url = 'https://www.hostname.com/'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_proxies({"http":"username:passwd@X.X.X.X:port",
                "https":"username:passwd@X.X.X.X:port"})
br.set_handled_schemes(['http', 'https'])
br.open(url)
```